Missing Website Groups and History Disappearance in Microsoft Edge – Seeking Solutions
I have a habit of grouping websites and saving them in groups on my browser, so that I can access them later. In Chrome, there is an option to save groups, but for some reason, it's not available in Edge. This has been my problem with Edge. I had saved many websites in groups, but whenever there was an Edge update, they would disappear from my recent menu. However, after the recent Edge update a few days ago, they not only disappeared from the recent menu but also seem to be completely gone. I thought of recovering them from browsing history, but Microsoft Edge doesn't even show history from four months ago. What's going on? It's 2024, and even with people having 1-2 TB storage, Microsoft Edge doesn't seem to save browsing history beyond four months.
Is there any solution to recover my browsing history from the past four months or even sessions from 2-3 days ago? Please, if anyone has a solution, I would greatly appreciate the help.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Groups are badly implemented in Microsoft Edge, perhaps because the focus
is on
Collections,
which are saved across sessions.
If you can't find your websites in History (Ctrl+H),
then there is no way to recover the groups.
You could in the future pin the tab group. This may make it more enduring
and more resistant to such problems.

Thank you for your response, harrymc I had already pinned all the groups before, and I understand that recovering my old history is very challenging. Even Microsoft customer support couldn't provide a solution. However, I have a hunch that there might be some solution out there. Perhaps my history is saved in Microsoft's data because I've noticed active files related to history in their data. So, maybe I can recover it from there. Let's see if anyone knows a solution.
